# Render PHP HTML page from variable

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Say I have a variable of a string that contains an html page. Within that html page variable I have an echo statement- 
e.g. `<?php echo 'whatever' ?>`

Can I somehow "render" that variable to the browser, and have php evaluate all the php statements within the variable?

If I just echo the variable, the html renders fine but the php statements are not evaluated.
If I try running eval on the entire page, it just throws an exception (makes sense).

I know this all sounds like bad practice, but I'm trying to figure out a way to do this without saving the variable to a file and loading the file.

BTW: I'm doing this all within codeigniter, so if there's a way to use $this->load->view on that variable... that would be even better :)

Example Code:

```
$x = /* Some logic to get a template data from another server */
/* $x is "<html><?php echo 'bla'; ?></html> */
echo $x;
```

This doesn't work- trying to run `echo eval($x)` also doesn't work

Comment: take a look at eval() function  from the manual :http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: show your code pls what have u tried?

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#returning-views-as-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write view data to variable and use this variable in other view

In you controller:

```
$data['view1'] = $this->load->view('my_view1', '', TRUE); // write view data to variable
$this->load->view('my_view2', $data);
```

In my_view2:

```
<html>
<?=$view1?>
</html>
```

This docs can help you [Returning views as data - Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#returning-views-as-data)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow you, but I think this is what you want.

If `page1_view.php` contains HTML and needs to echo a variable. e.g.

```
<div>Foo says: <?php echo $whatever; ?>!!!</div>
```

To get that "view" as a string with the variable `$whatever` evaluated you need this.

```
$view_data['whatever'] = "Hello World";
$page1 = $this->load->view('page1_view', $view_data, TRUE);
```

`$page1` now contains a string which is the contents of `page1_view.php`. in this case

```
"<div>Foo says: Hello World!!!</div>"
```

Comment: I don't have a file in my hand (what you called page1_view.php), I have it's contents as a variable ("<div>Foo says: <?php echo $whatever; ?>!!!</div>
")